# How to delete mysql database through shell command

Tags: mysql, database, linux, shell, ubuntu

I use the pylons and sqlalchemy. I constantly update the schema files and delete and recreate the database so that new schema can be made.

Every time I do this by opening the MySql Query Browser and login and delete the database/schema.

**How do I delete the MySQL db/schema thorough linux shell commands in Ubuntu Linux?**

Comment: This works on any OS not just linux

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
mysqladmin -h[hostname/localhost] -u[username] -p[password] drop [database]
```

Comment: Your password will be accessible to any other user on the system.  `ps aux`.  Consider using a `.my.cnf` instead.

Comment: I'm newbie to shell scripting, but for those of you who found this looking for a method to drop and create db from inside your script, this method worked for me.

Comment: if you want to see for yourself without logging in if indeed your database is blown away, I fancy `mysqlshow -u [username] -p[Password]`. You can even grep for the database as well `mysqlshow -u [username] -p[password] | grep [database]`.

Comment: Without spaces between -u and username for sure?

Comment: Is there any way to drop all the databases with a single command instead of writing down the command for each DB?

Comment: any way to do it without the confirmation prompt?

Answer (score 42):

In general, you can pass any query to `mysql` from shell with -e option.

```
mysql -u username -p -D dbname -e "DROP DATABASE dbname"
```

Comment: Your password will be accessible to any other user on the system.  `ps aux`.  Consider using a `.my.cnf` instead.

Comment: Or maybe just make a note that this is only for your local development environment where you are the only user.

Comment: The -D flag is not needed to DROP a database.
It should be enough with:
`mysql -uuser -ppass -e "DROP DATABASE dbname"`

Answer (score 29):

If you are tired of typing your password, create a (chmod 600) file `~/.my.cnf`, and put in it:

```
[client]
user = "you"
password = "your-password"
```

For the sake of conversation:

```
echo 'DROP DATABASE foo;' | mysql
```

Comment: although it is development environment, I really not much worried about password visible to others. I like your .my.cnf idea very much. +1 on the idea

Comment: For automatic script, second part of answer is the best. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Another suitable way:

```
$ mysql -u you -p
<enter password>

>>> DROP DATABASE foo;
```

Comment: That's basically the same as what he's been doing.

Comment: Illustrating the possiblities on the command line does not warrant a down vote.  He was using MySql Query Browser.  Not quite the same.

Comment: But the problem statement clearly states that he wants a "shell command".

Answer (score 11):

No need for mysqladmin:

just use mysql command line

```
mysql -u [username] -p[password] -e 'drop database db-name;'
```

This will send the drop command although I wouldn't pass the password this way as it'll be exposed to other users of the system via **ps aux**

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has discontinued drop database command from mysql client shell. Need to use mysqladmin to drop a database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It does not answer the question directly since the question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove database directly as:

$ mysqladmin -h **[host]** -u **[user]** -p drop **[database_name]**

**[Enter Password]**

Do you really want to drop the 'hairfree' database [y/N]: **y**

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@host]# mysqladmin -u root -p drop [DB]

Enter password:******
```

Comment: I don't think this exposes the password to other users on the server, like many of the other answers do; instead the user is asked for it after the user hits enter. Possibly people haven't realised this when they downvoted what are possibly the best two answers!