# How can I drop a MySQL database from a bash script without being asked for confirmation?

Tags: mysql, bash

I have written a bash script, which creates a database dump of an existing database and then creates an identical copy from this dump under a different name. Then some actions are performed on the copied database for testing. After the tests are performed, the copied database is not needed anymore and should be dropped.

I currently use the following command in my script to perform the dropping of the copied database:

```
mysql -h"$HOST" -P"$PORT" -u"$ROOT_USER" -p"$DB_PW" -e "drop database $DB_COPY"
```

This does work and the database is dropped. However, I am asked for a password to confirm the dropping every time. Although I understand the purpose of the confirmation, dropping a database can potentially be disastrous of course, it is unnecessary in this case. I would prefer if I could force the drop without confirmation.

I also tried the following command instead, but the results are the same:

```
mysqladmin -h"$HOST" -P"$PORT" -u"$ROOT_USER" -p"$DB_PW" -e "drop database $DB_COPY"
```

In the manpages for `mysql`, I found the `-f` option, but it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for since I am still asked for a password. The same is happening, when I use the `-f` option with the `mysqladmin` command in my script.

However, when I try the second command directly in the shell with the `-f` option (i.e. standalone from my script) as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530492/how-do-you-force-a-mysql-command-from-the-command-line-to-not-prompt-y-n), I'm not asked for the password. I did not include any confirmation prompt in my script, so I'm a bit puzzled where it comes from. The script itself is currently run as the `root` user, so I don't think it's the OS prompting me for the password. The confirmation prompt I get looks like this:

```
Enter password:
```

I also tried the following, since it was suggested in the linked thread, but the results are the same:

```
yes | mysqladmin -h"$HOST" -P"$PORT" -u"$ROOT_USER" -p"$DB_PW" -f drop "$DB_COPY"
```

Am I overlooking something or is there any other option I can use to bypass the confirmation and just drop the database immediately? Or can anybody point me to the source of this prompt and/or a way to suppress it?

Comment: Can't you send the password from within your script? Maybe in the way it is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205180/how-to-pass-password-to-mysql-command-line).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I see the `-p` option being suggested in that thread and as you can see in my code samples, I already do use that. However, I'm still asked for a password.

Comment: According to [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql), your approach looks reasonable for me. First, I would check whether the variable really contains the correct password (`xxd <<<$DB_PW`). If this looks good, I would try another command to see whether you are asked for a password. This would tell us whether the problem is related to that specific sql command.

Comment: I double-checked the password variable and it turns out, I really made an error there. I changed the name of the variable previously and overlooked one occurence, where I didn't change it accordingly. Thus, the content of the variable wasn't what it should have been. The error is now fixed and using the `mysqladmin` command with the `-f` option now drops the database without asking for the password. Thanks, I think I would have missed that!

Comment: For this reason, I always put  `set -u` into the scripts I'm developing ....

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate, but the accepted answer of the similar question is basically "LOL, IDK."