# delete database with cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sql-delete

I need to know how can I delete or drop a database every 6 hour with cron jobs and them create it with a demo .sql.
in my cpanel I create the cron like this:

```
0   0   1   *   *   /home/escyv/restore_data.sh
```

and the cron execute the command but don't made any drop o truncate when the cron jobs execute the command.

here the script:

restore_data.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
clear;
#fill in your database information here
user="escyv_cyv";
password="ky21m1";
server="localhost";
database_name="escyv_cyv";

#path to the backup database file
restore_file="0db0/escyv_db.sql";

#here the script deletes all your tables in the database
mysql --user=$user --password=$password -h $server -BNe "SHOW TABLES" $database_name | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//' | awk '{print "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " $1 ";SET
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"}' | mysql --user=$user --password=$password -h $server $database_name;

echo "Base de datos limpiandose!";
echo "Restaurando Base de Datos..";

#here the script restores the database
mysql --user=$user --password=$password host=$server $database_name < $restore_file;

echo "Base de datos restaurada!";
```

I test it change it the name of the restore file escyv_db.sql to escyv_db1.sql to see if the site show error but show me the entire info in the database...so I think the command is not made nothing..

sorry for my bad english...is not my mother language

Best Regards!

Andrés

**-----EDIT-----
this script is working!**  *thanks to @itsols*

This is the new restore_data.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
clear;

#here the script deletes all your tables in the database
mysql -u escyv -pky21m1 -e 'drop database escyv_cyv;'

echo "Base de datos limpiandose!";

mysql -u escyv -pky21m1 -e 'create database escyv_cyv;'

#here the script restores the database

mysql -u escyv_cyv -pky21m1 escyv_cyv < 0db0/escyv_db.sql

echo "Restaurando Base de Datos..";

echo "Base de datos restaurada!";
```

Comment: Is this your OWN local server or a hosted one. If it's a third party hosted server, generally, you cannot do DB deletes unless you have the right privileges. The same goes for creating a DB. This is mainly for security reasons. But I'm not sure if this is your case.

Comment: hello @itsols is in a hosted one in gator, and I have the privileges because I can zip the entire folder and backup the db

Comment: `DROP DATABASE` are separate privileges.

Comment: mmm.. I will ask to support if I have that privileges...

Comment: the support in gator told me that I can the DROP DATABASE if I have the user and the pass of the database

Comment: Don't forget that context is limited in a cron job. Usually, you have to specify full path  where your commands are located.

Comment: yes and the cron do the command because I put my mail into the cron job so when any cron execute any command sent me an email and show me if the command execute well or don't...and with the command I put in my question the cron sent me an succesfully email...but don't drop the database tables...in the command "show tables" works because in the mail show me all tables in the db but don't drop them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working WITH a DB requires certain privileges. So, for example, you may read a DB, process records in it and Create a BACKUP (which is usually a text file).

However, mainly due to security reasons, you are not given the privileges to create a DB or drop one using the permissions given by a host. So is very unlikely that gator will give you that privilege.

I'd recommend an approach where you create/drop tables identified by the user. This way you can restrict access to the individual tables and backup only those specific tables. For example, if you have a user named X, your table can be called tblXSomeTable. The user name after the letters tbl, help identify ownership of the DB.

Comment: the support team in gator told me that I have that privileges and I can drop or create,etc in cron job if I know the username and the password of the database.  here textually the answer of them "If you have the mysql username and password for the database, you should be able to drop the database using a cron job. "

Comment: A good way to check this would be to simply try a create or drop db command through a shell script and run it directly (not as a cron) then you can make sure if it works. Alternatively, you may try running a php program where the drop db is done using system/exec. For testing the script directly, you'll need terminal access.

Comment: hello, can you give me a clue to how generated this shell script with drop database?

Comment: Here's an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050581/how-to-delete-mysql-database-through-shell-command But I doubt this will work on your live host as you cannot get that level of permission. In any case, double check with your host.

Comment: its works that delete my entire database, here the command `mysql -u escyv -pky21m1 -e 'drop database escyv_cyv;'` them I create the database with this command `mysql -u escyv -pky21m1 -e 'create database escyv_cyv;'` but when I try to insert the data into the database give me this error:  /home/escyv/restore_data.sh: line 13: /0db0/escyv_db.sql: No such file or directory but in that path is in fact the file with all data in sql....

Comment: TWO issues. First, you have posted your user name and password. Now be careful when posting commands that contain identification like this. Second, the path can be verified by cpanel itself or by contacting your host. The path is NOT /home like you've given. There must be a server/domain prefix somewhere. Ask your host this information.

Comment: Thank you, the error was in the `/` before..this is the right command that is working in my gator host `mysql -u escyv_cyv -pky21m1 escyv_cyv > 0db0/escyv_db.sql`.  thank you for your support. Best Regards!