# drop database if exists using mysqladmin in linux

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a command to drop a database if exists from mysql. I want to execute the command in terminal and not using mysql query. Using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050581/how-to-delete-mysql-database-through-shell-command) answer I found that I can drop database from terminal using

`mysqladmin -h[hostname/localhost] -u[username] -p[password] drop [database]`

How do I do the same thing using if-exists condition?

Comment: And where were you thinking of coding this `IF` statement?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for `mysqladmin` to add "IF EXISTS" to its drop database. It is hard-coded to accept a name of a database only, not any other syntax.

Here is [line of code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysqladmin.cc#L1238) that formats the DROP DATABASE statement in the mysqladmin client:

```
sprintf(name_buff, "drop database `%.*s`", FN_REFLEN, db);
```

But you may not need IF EXISTS. Just try to drop the database. If it doesn't exist, the client will print an error, but the effect is the same.

Here's a demo I just ran in my shell:

```
$ mysqladmin -f drop test2
mysqladmin: DROP DATABASE test2 failed;
error: 'Can't drop database 'test2'; database doesn't exist'
```

The client will exit with status of 1. If you don't like that (like if you're running in a shell script with `set -e` in effect), you can suppress the exit status:

```
mysqladmin -f drop test2 || true
```

If you don't like to see the error message, you can redirect it:

```
mysqladmin -f drop test2 2>/dev/null || true
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use 'e' argument, like :
mysql -u root -p somedb -e "select * from mytable" ?